# Sound card problems

Tags: windows-7, audio, sound-card

My dolby soundcard is broken but i can still get sound through the built in windows output, some programs like skyrim, google chrome and VLC still run with sound but the majorty of games and programs will either play with no sound or wont play at all when they cannot detect a sound card, most also do not have an option to change the sound output that they use.
Short of getting my laptop repaired/buying a new sound card, does anyone know how i can get programs to use the built in windows sound output?

Comment: Some times you have to set this in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the default playback device to anything other than the Dolby sound card.

1. Right-click on the "Speaker" icon on the taskbar.
2. Select **Playback devices**
3. Select the appropriate device and click **Set Default**
4. Click **Apply**

[image]

Comment: Nope, it only shows the one speaker option which is already set as default and that is the one that doesnt work. It will also not allow me to unselect it or modify it in anyway.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the drivers for the sound card? Also check the BIOS if you can somehow disable it and enable the non-Dolby one, if such an option exists.

Comment: Yup, deleted dolby and redownloaded and installed but no effect.